# Accessing envied values inside build.gradle

Tags: flutter, environment-variables, build.gradle, mobile-development

I'm building a Flutter app with multiple flavors (similar to [Working with multiple env files](https://github.com/petercinibulk/envied/issues/16)), and I need to access the Envied class inside my `app/build.gradle` file as shown in the code below to get the google_maps_api_key - (firebaseAndroidApiKeyDev). How can I solve this?

```
 productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "app"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "App Dev"
            resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", firebaseAndroidApiKeyDev  
        }
        prod {
      //More flavors configs....
```

I went trough the [envied docs](https://pub.dev/packages/envied) and asked GPT about it but still got no clue on how to solve this. I opened an issue in their repo as well ([Accessing envied values inside build.gradle](https://github.com/petercinibulk/envied/issues/63)).

There are similar questions in StackOverflow: [How to read a properties files and use the values in project Gradle script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101589/how-to-read-a-properties-files-and-use-the-values-in-project-gradle-script), [How to include additional configuration file inside build.gradle file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335857/how-to-include-additional-configuration-file-inside-build-gradle-file), [How to create a file and set in environment variable and get the data inside the file in build.gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54344610/how-to-create-a-file-and-set-in-environment-variable-and-get-the-data-inside-the) but they refer strictly to the native-android side of development, and I need to access to a Flutter generated class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access some key inside the flutter code as native you can use (among some other options) the package [flutter_config](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_config).
In the description of the package there is a well-documented example, but in general:

1 - Create an .env file (which you include in the .gitignore so you don't share it publicly) with the key-value structure:

```
API_URL=https://myapi.com
FABRIC_ID=abcdefgh
```

NOTE: btw, you don't need to obfuscate the key if it is in a .env file, just not share it or uploadit to your git (In the case of android when doing a release, you need to configure a couple more stuff to make sure the .env file is not shared as part of the app, but again, just a simple configurations)

2 - Initialize it in your `main.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_config/flutter_config.dart';

void main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // Required by FlutterConfig
   await FlutterConfig.loadEnvVariables();

   runApp(MyApp());
}
```

3 - At flutter level you can access those variables using:

```
import 'package:flutter_config/flutter_config.dart';

FlutterConfig.get('FABRIC_ID') // returns 'abcdefgh'
```

4 - At native level you can access [(Android)](https://github.com/ByneappLLC/flutter_config/blob/master/doc/ANDROID.md):

4.1 - After the line `apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"` in the `build.gradle`, add:

```
apply from: project(':flutter_config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"
```

This line configures the plugin in android

4.2 - Load it in the `build.gradle`:

```
defaultConfig {
     applicationId project.env.get("APP_ID")
}
```

For more explained docs go to:

- [The oficial docs of the plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_config)
- [The specific docs for Android](https://github.com/ByneappLLC/flutter_config/blob/master/doc/ANDROID.md)

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to add api key in build.gradle. Create flavours folder inside `android/app/src/` like

[image: flavour folder structure]

Define api key inside android/app/scr/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest ...
  <application ...
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
               android:value="@string/map_api_key"/>
```

Inside each folder create a res folder and inside res folder create values then create strings.xml

[image: strings.xml]

Inside strings.xml add map api key

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="map_api_key">12345678910</string>
</resources>
```

That should fetch the relevant key for different flavors

Comment: Hello Kaushik, with your approach I wouldn't be achieving my 2 main concerns:
1. Obfuscate the secret API KEY value (in a res.xml is far from being secret - even with android native obfuscation and stuff)
2. Accesing the values "hidden" in the envied generated file from my Flutter side as I asked.

Comment: There is no way you can obfuscate keys as you expect. Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473527/how-to-hide-api-keys-in-androidmanifest-xml